# In Aliens vs Predator, why does Predator bother dissolving the “evidence”?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-vs.-predator

I don’t understand why the predator bothers using the dissolving liquid? He is leaving his own evidence everywhere, skinning the cop? Why bother dissolving everyone that has had a Xenomorph burst out of their chest? Also, no markings showing he is a hunter, no carved tusks?

Comment: “Why bother dissolving everyone that has had a Xenomorph burst out of their chest?” That question kind of answers itself with the word Xenomorph. Nuke it from orbit, only way to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

The predator is there as a clean up man. His killings leave no trace evidence that the humans can make use of. The alien victims though could have traces of alien DNA and the predators do not want humans getting a hold of that.

Comment: To be fair probably would have been better to have held these "games" on another planet!

Comment: @E_McAndrew Possibly, but they built all of their alien hunting grounds on Earth long before humans were even close to understanding what DNA was.

Comment: I’m not arguing with your answer, I just think the actual logic is flawed. Like we don’t want to let humans know so we’ll do this on Earth. Was Pippin organizing this? “The closet to danger you are the farther from harm. It’s the last thing they’ll expect”

Comment: @E_McAndrew I suspect that for this movie, as with much fiction, that however much time you spend noticing plot holes and logic flaws will be a lot longer than the writers spent trying to avoid plot holes and logic flaws.